# Book: Earthlings find (new) nearby planet that also hosts humans and an inorganic species robot-knowledge depository

Tags: story-identification, books, hard-sci-fi

I am trying to remember the title of a book that I read years ago. I have not had success in recent months in finding the title.

**Plot Summary** (from what I remember)**:**

Earth is overpopulated and humans are still trying to explore nearby stars for future habitable planets. One day, out of nowhere, a perfectly habitable planet pops up relatively nearby. A group of maybe 12 total scientists, scholars, experts, etc., set off on a mission to investigate the planet.

They find that humans have already populated the planet and there are ultra-advanced technology there. The crew is shocked and not everyone is quick to warm up to the new humans there. Later, it is found that the humans were created by a single machine on the planet that is a repository of a previous organic species. The old organic species was facing impending doom, so they passed on all they knew to this machine and sent it off to go help other life survive their potential dooms. In this instance, the Earth needed a solar radiation shield of some sort to stop a solar storm that was coming in *N* number of years.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the asks! I have estimates for your questions, but keep in mind that my answers may not be accurate due to lack of memory. Firstly, the book might have been between 10-20 years old. Secondly, the exploration was most likely centered on a nearby star; I misspoken using "galaxies".